# What are examples of ORTHOGONAL function space for multivariable functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, orthogonality, multivalued-functions

- What are examples of orthogonal spaces of multivariable functions?

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2911700/553404) and learned that $$\langle f(x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n),g(x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n) \rangle = \idotsint_D f(x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n) \overline{g(x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n)} dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n$$.

Comment: For real-valued functions on a given domain a dot product can be defined as the integral over that domain of the product of those functions and a fixed non-negative weight function. The spherical harmonics are an example.

Comment: @random Does that requires multiple integrals?

Comment: For a multidimensional variable space that is to be expected.